# Race condition between edit and vote leaves vote locked

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

This is regarding [What natural ingredients can be used to color food blue or green?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22475/what-foods-spices-can-be-used-to-make-natural-food-colorings)

This is also covered by [Your vote is now locked in unless edited, even though it *was* edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70574/your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-edited-even-though-it-was-edited)

When I first loaded that question, and started reading it, it was showing [the first revision](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/revisions/22475/1). I went ahead and downvoted it. Later, I come back, and see [Aaronut's revision](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/revisions/22475/2), and try and redact my downvote. The site informs me that my vote is locked unless the question is edited. Which of course, it has been—I voted on the first revision. But I guess Aaronut's edit was actually between when I loaded the page and when I clicked the down arrow. Guess you shouldn't spend much time considering your vote…

*I suggest that the revision number I'm looking at should be sent to the server along with my vote, and the server should reject the vote if there is a newer revision. Naturally, a proper error message should be displayed ("this post has been edited since you've started reading it, please refresh the page…").*

[Apologies in advance if I was supposed to do something to the other question; not sure how one "re-opens" a bug on meta.SO. But it sounds like Jeff declined it due to it being a lot of work, but the suggestion to just check revision numbers should make reasonably easy to implement, I hope.]

Comment: I guess this couldn't *hurt*, but it does seem like potentially a lot of development work for something that you could easily work around by just editing yourself...

Comment: Besides, I think more generally, you should consider your vote less on the stylistic or grammatical appeal of a question and more on the *substantive* aspects. I will vote a question up even if I think to myself, "This would be a really good question if it were edited into shape", then I click the "edit" link. Downvotes are probably best used for questions that are not useful or constructive, or those that are completely beyond the help of a few edits.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, the edit turns it from a poll to something that maybe isn't. (The later edits do this even better). I suppose of course I could have done that myself (like, e.g., with http://cooking.stackexchange.com/revisions/17720/3) but… well, time is finite. At least I checked back to make sure my vote was still valid.

Comment: We're [experimenting with in-place, real-time updates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) and unobtrusively informing of edits is on the list to try.  We'll revisit this issue once it's implemented.

Comment: We are going through old bug reports, is this still an issue?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I haven't had it happen again, but I'm not sure how long it is between an edit being submitted and the "this post has been edited" notice showing up. If it's short, I guess it's fixed.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas is there a sandbox Stack Exchange for me to test this on?

Comment: Not really, I'm going to status-complete this one but if it happens again report it.