# Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, grace-period

When answers are posted within a question's initial grace period, it is possible that further edits could completely change the question (see "[chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)"), and render those first few answers incorrect.

Worse yet, nobody is notified that there was a change to the question, except those that are sitting on the page *and* notice the edit bar pop in. And of those, only those bothered enough to open it in a new window to compare the differences, will see how much was changed.

After the grace period is up, nobody will be able to consolidate why the first few answers actually answered a different question. And the answerers won't know unless someone comments or down-votes (and in the latter case, without context, they still might have trouble understanding, unless they memorized the question's initial state).

Jon Skeet stated it pretty well in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/make-first-draft-of-a-new-answer-part-of-the-permanent-revision-history/168295#comment387564_138017) on [a different feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138017/):

> I'd like this to apply to the question, as well as answers. Sometimes I (or others) have added perfectly good answers, but then the question has been changed within the grace period, making answers look foolish without any indication of what's happened.

So this time, my proposal is quite simple:

> Once an answer is posted to a question within the initial grace period, a new grace period should start, and the current state of the question should be saved as the first revision. Further edits within the next 5 minutes will be aggregated into a new, second revision.

This will only noticeably affect questions where answers are posted within the grace period *and* the author of the question makes edits within 5 minutes of the first answer. (Effectively, it would treat it as if a *different* user made an edit within the author's grace period.) All other scenarios will continue to behave as they do today.

This feature request comes close:

[Add an indication that a post has been edited in the 5 minutes grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period)

However, the answer suggests a simple change to the wording or a pencil icon (like we see with edited comments), without adding a revision that can be viewed and compared. I don't think this is enough - in some cases it's going to be important to know *what changed*, not just when.

Comment: What would make this request more actionable is if you could demonstrate some questions where this has happened. </snarkasm>

Comment: @billinkc happened to me, too. But it was in my early days on Drupal Answers, so i can't find it using recently deleted list. I've seen a question, answered, then I have seen it again, flagged duplicate, one moderator closed it, then first one was edited, another moderator reopened second question, and I have started to accumulate downvotes as my answer was under wrong question... without any way to prove what happened. If any of the diamonds wants to search Drupal Answers, it will be there somewhere.

Comment: @Mołot Bill is making a joke; there was a big hubbub about one of my other feature requests when a certain person asked for proof. The very nature of the problem makes it extremely difficult to prove. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand oh, OK. But there is a proof somewhere in my flags and questions' close and reopen history. Well, anyway, I just wanted to say it does happen, so I did. It still irritates me.

Comment: @Mołot yes, agreed, I've seen it happen many times, but very rarely to me (I often write answers detailed enough that I'm not finished within the grace period). So coming up with examples might be problematic, but if anyone else has any, I'll be happy to incorporate them.

Comment: Need to think about this a bit more, but at first glance I rather like it. Avoids the UI clutter problem inherent in [the previous request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Jarrod whipped this up this past week, and the behavior should now be live. Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present at the time the edit is submitted:

- The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
- A non-deleted comment on the post that was posted after the previous revision by anyone *other than* the editor exists
- A non-deleted answer to the question that was posted after the previous revision exists (even if the answer was posted by the editor)
- The previous revision was a rollback
- The new revision is a rollback
- ([as of April 3rd, 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341105/closure-should-end-the-grace-period-for-edits)) The question was closed after the previous revision.
- ([as of May 13, 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378754/377214)) The editor has less than 10 reputation.

The way you phrased your request is a bit odd and does not quite match the implementation, but the intent is clear and I believe the changes satisfy the need.

Comment: Does condition 1, 2, 4 and 5 also apply to answers?

Comment: Everything applies to everything. Figure out how to post an answer to it, grace period ends.

Comment: he went to jarrod's!

Comment: @Shog9 I was guessing it did - asking for clarification was mostly rhetorical since I thought it should be clarified in the answer itself... =D

Comment: Would you consider close votes and flags to be worth adding to the list of conditions?

Comment: Shog, when a new answer is posted in a question, does this reset grace period of the other, earlier answer(s)? I am trying to figure whether this feature impacts issues discussed in [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773)

Comment: No, @gnat. I still think that's crazy.

Comment: I think that [meta-tag:fastest-gun] is crazy

Comment: Unless "more pointless arguments" is your idea of sanity, this does nothing for that.

Comment: don't know if you noticed, but that very feature makes a solid progress towards what scares you (not me) so much. Any reader with 50 repz can now "freeze" what they see by commenting, that very much close if not stronger than saving first draft

Comment: @gnat: the 'reset grace period' feature doesn't stop changes being made.  It just means that the changes are recorded when something around the question or answer changes, so that it is possible to go back in time and see the state of the question or answer when a comment was made (or when another answer was posted, or ...).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agree, I meant to say something like a snapshot is frozen. Further editing is of course possible, it is just, as you say, changes are now "explicitly recorded". I already observed the way how new feature works, looks impressive. You see comments and revision history clearly reflects changes made to address the comment, it is not buried within grace period anymore

Comment: Should closing/opening the question also make new revisions? That can help clarify edits made in response to such an action.

Comment: Shog, could you please take a look at [this issue recently raised at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341050/839601)? They say that dupehammer close didn't break grace period, likely because "possible duplicate" comment was removed too quickly. If this was indeed the case, would it make sense to add question closure to list of events that reset grace period?

Comment: That question was not edited after being posted, @Catija. (nor, so far as I can tell, has the author even returned to the site since then)

Comment: Ah. Ok. Clearly it was too early in the morning when I was reading it, then :P

Comment: Shog, how difficult would it be to add deletion to the list of events that cancel grace period? I ask because it appears that [fastest gun cheaters have recently got into a habit of abusing this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354470/839601 "as discussed here"), would be helpful if system had an audit trail for such tricks

Comment: ...they say the trick with deletion/undeletion during grace period can be exploited for plagiarism - if this is indeed so that's quite worrying

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275705/final-binding-votes-to-close-and-delete-should-trigger-a-revision-to-be-saved/275751#275751), @gnat

Comment: not quite certain if related, really - while decline over there makes good sense, it seems a different use case. Folks at MSO talk about immediate self-deletion of a placeholder answer when there is simply no chance of leaving a comment that would trigger grace reset. Basically it looks like system is giving an abuser 5 minutes of free reign when they can do whatever they want and this will leave no traces, no matter what they type in these 5 minutes (including plagiarism) will appear after undeletion as if it was genuinely posted 5 minutes ago. And my favorite comments trick won't work there

Comment: See the comment I left over on the discussion you linked, @gnat - the mechanical action is pretty common, but I see less evidence of *abuse*.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this answer up to date! I didn't know about the "less than 10 reputation" addition and was about to ask about it when I found this.