# Recognize edits that happened after the VLQ flag but during grace period as flag-validating ones

Tags: feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts, grace-period, fastest-gun

This feature request is posted as a follow-up to [discussion in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253865/839601) related to flagging very low quality "drafts" of *fastest gun* answers:

> edits to a post flagged as Very Low Quality will immediately dismiss that flag as helpful. So you really don't have to worry about flagging a post that's abysmally bad now - if it gets fixed before it gets into review, your flag will silently go away.
>
> **Q:** if edit happened after the flag but during grace period, can system distinguish that as a flag-validating edit?
>
> **A:** It *could*... but it currently *doesn't*. (went and tested this to make sure)

Suggest to enable system to recognize edits that happened after the VLQ flag but during grace period as flag-validating ones.

The way how things work now looks like breaking the intent stated in above quote: **"you really don't have to worry about flagging a post that's abysmally bad now..."**

Comment: So basically you're saying that ninja edits should automatically dismiss VLQ flags as helpful?  I'm not sure that's an improvement.  Maybe we should give folks the 5 minutes it probably takes to do a proper job on their post before removing the scrutiny that the VLQ flag brings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey all I say is current behavior doesn't match the intended one: "you really don't have to worry about flagging a post that's abysmally bad now..." In that sense, I would not mind request to be declined with an explanation like "hey we (SE team) changed our mind, flaggers must wait until fastest gun guys complete their tricks"

Comment: I still think you don't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "if it gets fixed before it gets into review, your flag will silently go away" -- this won't happen now: 1) flag is submitted against crappy "draft" 2) fastest gun edit brings post into shape during grace period 3) flag is _not_ dismissed 4) post enters the queue with an active flag and (surprise) in a proper shape

Comment: Hrm. A substantial edit, *maybe*... Otherwise, I think I agree with Robert here - it'd just be a great way for people to ensure they are *never* automatically flagged as VLQ since all it'd take would be a quick fake edit during the grace period.

Comment: @AnnaLear as [pointed above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231199/recognize-edits-that-happened-after-the-vlq-flag-but-during-grace-period-as-flag?noredirect=1#comment759640_231199), my primary concern as a flagger is whether I can rely on this statement or not: "you really don't have to worry about flagging a post that's abysmally bad now..." Whether you confirm or dismiss it, is of secondary importance. Just give me [rules of the game](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/conversation/poetry-of-flagging "'I'll decline all your flags unless they are haikus or limericks' - okay")

Answer (score 3):

Sort of workaround for this issue became available due to **[recent changes to the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773)**. Prior to flagging an answer that looks incomplete, one can ask to clarify this in comments. Like this:

> **this answer looks incomplete, why?**

Mentioned system change makes comments reset grace period, so that in case if author improves the post, there will be a guaranteed, *recognizable* new post revision after your comment.

For VLQ/NAA flags, new post revision will [automatically dismiss these as helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773).

Comment: this answer focuses on flagging because the question is about flagging. For a wider overview of the impact of new feature refer [Is it all right to flag very new answer as 'very low quality'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601) at MSO: "recent changes to the system send a fairly strong message on what is expected of you..."

Answer (score 2):

Don't really have an issue with this, but I also don't think it's really as much of a problem as folks think it is<sup>*</sup>.

Over the past 30 days, 85% of all Very Low Quality flags on Stack Overflow answers were marked helpful. For those raised within 5 minutes of a post's life, the helpful rate goes up to 87%. That leaves only 41 FGITW VLQ flags on Stack Overflow answers during this period that *weren't* helpful - 39 of which were marked "disputed" by review.

Determining which (if any) of these were *edited* during the grace period is do-able, but tedious - so let's do a quick sanity-check instead. Here are the 39 answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22929000
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22930737
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22934192
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22935140
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22977865
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22987925
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23008712
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23031233
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23054431
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23076476
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23079270
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23079339
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23105308
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23129105
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23158359
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23167995
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23196019
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23196447
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23199150
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23223609
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23269034
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23309740
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23319161
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23332576
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23333219
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23337963
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23405766
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23410807
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23418331
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23423164
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23428753
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23441360
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23457519
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23460210
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23462193
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23465576
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23492803
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23505746
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23518344

<sup>*<sub>Not that *anyone* here sleeps with the lights on for fear that the FGITW under their bed will eat them, mind you</sub></sup>

Comment: Just for scale: those are 39 flags out of a total of 4,354 raised during the past 30 days on SO. You have to be a FFITW to even have a *shot* at this problem.

Comment: so, what do you plan for - yay or nay? Not that this would stop me from fast flagging, I only prefer to know to better understand the implications. :) As for the frequency of flag / gun races, I think you can generally expect its increase as more and more flaggers learn about [great power of the queue](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2584/168) brought in by recent changes (_really_ nice job on designing these by the way)