# Let's be smarter when rolling back in the grace-period

Tags: feature-request, notifications, revisions-list, rollbacks, grace-period

Currently, rollbacks [are never rolled into the previous revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876).

I propose a simple change making the rollback-link more useful:

**If the rollback is to the pre-edit revision, and an ordinary edit would be rolled into the previous revision, just pretend it was one.**

(The [resulting empty revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564) has the summary `[Edit removed during grace period]`.)

That avoids recording any more evidence than necessary of the brain-fart which led to the edit, reducing embarrassment and avoiding puzzlement to readers by de-cluttering the revision-history.

Also, reverting all changes does not retract the notification ([tested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25119941#25119941) with [Mogsdad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/206345)), thus a second proposal:

**If the edit-notification was not yet signalled to the user, squash it. After all, there's nothing to see.**

Comment: As an aside: until two years ago *manually* undoing an edit would hide it from the revision history altogether (while in the meantime one could have silently removed or changed an old, locked-in vote). But that was fixed [in May 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history/180564#180564).

Comment: would that allow for stealth vote unlock?

Comment: @gnat: Unfortunately(?) no more than the current system.

Comment: @gnat: There's still an entry in the edit history (see the edit history on this question for my test), so not so much "stealth."

Comment: I just got bit by this today because I thought a rollback would trigger the edit merge mechanism. It is really unintuitive that you're supposed to *not* use the "undo your edit" button to undo your edit if you want to trigger this.