# Why is edit history being logged during the grace period?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/367912/revisions

The initial post occurred at 2018-03-19 15:37:03Z.

The first edit (second revision) occurred at 2018-03-19 15:38:52Z and the second edit (third revision) occurred at 2018-03-19 15:40:11Z.

Comment: Maybe a (now deleted) comment was posted in the mean time?

Comment: Do we now short-circuit the grace period if someone else comments?

Comment: @Glorfindel comment's not even deleted.

Comment: @Catija that's another comment, between the 1st and 2nd revisions. Robert talks about the 2nd and 3rd revisions. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/367912/timeline

Comment: @Glorfindel Nope. First comment was at 15:38:25, second revision was stamped at 15:38:52. The question seems to be about all of the revisions, not just the third?

Comment: @Catija that's correct and publicly visible. Robert is talking about the first edit and second edit, corresponding to the 2nd revision and 3rd revision: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUS1p.png

Comment: @Glorfindel Considering that Robert was unaware that edits did this at all, How about we're both right?

Answer (score 4):

For the past couple of years, [a comment by a 3rd-party will end the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876).

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I stopped tracking changes like this at about the same time.

Comment: Yep, I was initially tripped up by this too because during my previous period of participation, this wasn't the case.

Comment: This explains the creation of the 2nd revision, but not the 3rd one. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUS1p.png

Comment: Ironically, that grace period was ended by [a comment expressing surprise at the ending of the first grace period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOVrh.png), @Glorfindel

Comment: Thanks, so my [first guess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308151/edit-history-being-logged-during-grace-period/308152?noredirect=1#comment1003939_308151) was correct :)