# When exactly does Stack Exchange make a new version of what you edit?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

As you know, when you edit a post in SE communities (like SO), sometimes your edition will be a new version, and sometimes else the current post will be just updated.

According to some tests, I figured it out:

- when there is a comment under the post after the last version, it will create a new version if you edit the post.
- When 10 minutes passed since the last edition, then it will create a new version if you edit the post.

Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's about it. Edits by other people also cause a new revision, and the so-called [grace-period](/questions/tagged/grace-period) lasts 5 minutes, not 10, and comments also end the grace period if they are quickly deleted (which might lead to [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308151/why-is-edit-history-being-logged-during-the-grace-period/308152#comment1003951_308152)). Votes and flags do not count, and neither do [deleting and undeleting your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/310275/revisions).