# Built-in (or recommended safe) way to post a link to an image inside a comment?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, hyperlinks, images

Screenshots are *so* useful. Is there a built-in way to upload an image that produces a link that can be shared inside a comment (since images can't be put into comments directly)?

If not, what is a recommended fallback service that could be recommended that is trustworthy for Stack Overflow users to click on? I don't want to share links that won't be clicked on due to users not recognizing the URL as a safe site to visit.

EDIT: Someone suggested this might be a duplicate of [Is it possible to add images to comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/is-it-possible-to-add-images-to-comments/85501#85501) - however it is a different question. I'm aware that embedding images isn't possible within comments and wasn't asking about that. I'm clearly asking what the preferred/trustworthy way of sharing *links* to images is inside of comments, hence, a different question.

Comment: Stack Overflow? Do you mean Stack Exchange?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+link+screenshot+in+comment) of [Is it possible to add images to comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85501/289905).

Comment: Not the same question. I already know it's not possible to embed an image in a comment and wasn't looking for a method to do so. I was asking for the safest and/or a built-in way to share a *link* to an image in a comment. ;-)

Comment: I retracted my close vote and your post is fine for a reopen vote soon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Start writing an answer
2. Upload an image there
3. Copy the generated link (it's an `i.stack.imgur.com` URL, hopefully users will recongize it)
4. Paste it into your comment
5. Profit!

Comment: Ok nice workaround! In fact this answers both parts of my question, as it's made apparent that imgur.com would be that "safe"/recognized service to use... Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively: click to edit the question, do the same thing, and cancel the edit without submitting. This is useful when the question is closed.

Comment: @Laurel I thought I never posted a comment with an image on a closed question, but [it turns out I did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308151/why-is-edit-history-being-logged-during-the-grace-period#comment1003948_308151). (Found with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1346716/comments-with-images-posted-on-closed-questions).)