# Can mods see answer drafts from other users?

Tags: support, answers, moderator-tools, moderators, draft

Yesterday I posted [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203558/68764), about 5 minutes after I clicked on the "Post Your Answer" button I got some comments from a mod.

In one of them he said I had edited my answer in the first 5 minutes after posted and so that edit won't show up on the edit history. The thing is that I didn't make any edits to the answer (before or after the first 5 minutes).

He was pretty convinced that I had done those edits, so now the only theory that I have is that he was able to see the draft of the answer while I was writing it, that would explain why he saw different versions of the answer (the parts he said I added were at the end of the answer, so that would make sense).

So the question is, can moderators see answer drafts from other users?

Note: some of the comments are now deleted, so only mods/staff would be able to see the full thread, but this question still can be answered without seeing the complete thread.

Comment: @KevinB the network activity could be there because of the draft beign saved, if after saved is visible or not to mods is my question

Comment: It gets sent for validation whenever the input is blurred looks like. The saving of the draft is more likely to be client-side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no interface to see a saved draft of a post. The disagreement about the response/timing of your answer likely boils down to a basic mix-up on one side or the other. Since the only artifact remaining is a set of deleted he-said-she-said comments, I wouldn't dwell on it any further and just move on. There's no backroom access.

Comment: Are Stack Exchange staff able to see drafts?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog Not to my knowledge, unless you have core dev access and dig into the deepest bowels of raw database storage. There's no interface to see that stuff; it is temporary scrap storage. There is no reasonable use case to explore it.

Answer (score 6):

### No.

I'm a moderator on one SE site, and we definitely can't see drafts before they're posted. (Stack Exchange staff probably can, but I don't know, and that's not what you're asking about anyway.)

It *is* often possible to detect so-called "shadow edits" (edits to a post made within the first 5 minutes of posting, which don't show up in the revision history) simply by watching the page carefully and *seeing* the post change. For example, I shadow-edited the current paragraph into this meta answer. If you're quick, you may see it change as you're reading it. Perhaps in your case the moderator somehow *thought* they saw this happen when in fact it didn't?

Comment: The term is "grace period", and [there are some exceptions when it's reset before 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/241919)

Comment: @Bookends I know.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

Moderators can only see answers once they've been posted. The only people other than the owner who can see answer drafts are staff.