# Why were these two edits within 5 minutes not combined?

Tags: support, edits

According to [Why are trivial edits discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/392799):

> Edits made by the same editor in a short period of time are collapsed: no matter how many times a post is edited within a 5-minute window, only one revision is stored ...

In this [recent occurrence](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/75358/revisions), revisions 2 and 3 (by me) for the *question* are less than 2 minutes apart, and yet they weren't rolled into one revision.

I posted an answer between the edits, but it's not the first time I've done that. Shouldn't the timer be post-specific?

Comment: Was there a comment between the edits?

Comment: @Catija: comment as in under either the Q or A? Nope.

Comment: @Catija I don't see a comment; can you please check if there was a deleted one?

Comment: Did you post your answer between the edits?

Comment: @Catija: yep, but not the first time I do that (didn't realize it important), I think something has changed.

Comment: The answer resets the edit window. Any answer or comment does.

Comment: @Catija: copy that, thanks. Do I delete the post? Or is it a valid [bug]?

Comment: It’s been a feature since 2015. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Catija Since there is a check for same user for comments, is the fact that there is no such check for answers intentional, or a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [criteria for breaking the grace period](/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted), specifically these two bullets:

> - A comment has been added to the post after the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post after the previous revision

Note that while there is an explicit check for the same user when it comes to *comments*, there is no such check when it comes to *answers*. As such, your answer posted between the two edits broke the grace period.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or an intentional feature, but this wasn't clear in that post. I've edited it to make it more clear.